# Regex - How to remove last instance of the search value it finds?

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have multiple XML files that I need to delete a line from.  The same line exists in different sections of the file but I only need to delete the last instance it finds. For example -

- (Openning tag here)Simple name="DisplayValue" value="{?Consumer}" />
- (Openning tag here)Simple name="DisplayValue" value="{?Consumer}" />
- (Openning tag here)Simple name="DisplayValue" value="{?Consumer}" /> - *This is the line I need to delete*

This is the line in file.

[image]

[image]

I am using the Find in Files feature in Notepad++ to achieve this. Tia.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode (with dot all enabled):

```
Find:    (.*)Same Text(?:\r?\n|$)(.*)
Replace: $1$2
```

This should work because the initial `(.*)` capture group should match and capture all content up to, but not including, the *last* occurrence of `Same Text`.  Then, we also match and capture all content after this last occurrence.  Finally, we replace with just the first two capture groups, to effectively splice out the line you want to remove.

Comment: I have added a screenshot and the actual text I need to replace.  When I run it, I get 0 occurances were replaced. I do think it is something to do with the format of the line I am replacing though.  This is the line I need to remove but only the last instance it finds: <Simple name="DisplayValue" value="{?Consumer}" />

Comment: As my answer says, you need to check `. matches newline`

Comment: Checked now but still no data.  If I search for the line i need to delete alone it finds all the instances in the file but when I use (.*)Text here(?:\r?\n|$)(.*) then it doesnt..

Comment: @AleksandarZoric You need to escape `\?` a literal question mark in your pattern.

Comment: Yeah I tried that earlier but still running into the same issue.  Think I need to escape the curly braces too and possibly the double quotes also but tried it a few different ways and issue still persists.

Comment: Raw data: <Simple name="DisplayValue" value="{?Consumer}" />

Comment: You saved the day! I was missing 2 escapes. Thanks a lot for that.  Appreciate it.